# Dropzone.js and displaying request validation errors in Laravel 5.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, laravel-5.1, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to upload a file. In my controller method I have the following validation set up:

```
$this->validate($request, ['logo' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif']);
```

If the validation fails It throws a 422 server response with the validation errors as json

```
{"logo":["The logo must be an image.","The logo must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, gif."]}
```

With dropzone.js how can I parse error and insert into the following `<p>` tag:

```
@if ($errors->has('logo')) <p class="help-block" id="logo-error">{{ $errors->first('logo') }}</p> @endif
```

I have an errors event declared in my dropzone script but nothing seems to appear when I do a console.log:

```
var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$("#my-dropzone").dropzone({
  url: baseUrl + "/upload",
  paramName: "logo",
  uploadMultiple: false,
  maxFiles: 1,
  dictDefaultMessage: '',
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      console.log('addedfile...');
      if (this.files[1]!=null){
        this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
    this.on("thumbnail", function(file, dataUrl) {
      console.log('thumbnail...');
      $('.dz-image-preview').hide();
      $('.dz-file-preview').hide();
    });
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
      formData.append("_token", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    });
    this.on("success", function(file, res) {
      console.log('upload success...');
      $('#img-thumb').attr('src', res.path);
      $('input[name="logo"]').val(res.path);
    });

  },
  error: function(file, response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603779/5723524

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery here. Since you are using the Laravel validation it will return with a status of error. So that we could write whatever needed in the error event of the AJAX request you are making, ie. the dropzone initialization here. A sample code will be like following,

```
success: function(file, response) {
        $('.profile-image-wrapper').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.profile-image-error').html('');
    },
    error: function(file, response) {
        var $message = response.errors.profilePhoto;
        $('.profile-image-wrapper').addClass('has-error');
        $('.profile-image-error').html('<strong>' +  $message + '</strong');
    },
```

The "paramName" property for my dropzone initialization is "profilePhoto". So the error will also available in the same order.